# Datatables cannot read form inputs with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I've already search about this but my problem is a little different. I used `dataTables` js library for this, plus using laravel. Whenever I checked the checkbox inside the table and then click next to check other items, then click `add`, the only item/s that will be added is the item where the page is. For example I am in the first page, then I click the `item1` & `item2`, then I click the next page to select other items, clicking `item10` & `item16`, then If I click `add` the only item reads by php is the item that is in the current page. Please see the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.data-tables').dataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-3.2.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.4.2/b-colvis-1.4.2/b-flash-1.4.2/b-html5-1.4.2/b-print-1.4.2/cr-1.4.1/fc-3.2.3/fh-3.1.3/kt-2.3.2/r-2.2.0/rg-1.0.2/rr-1.2.3/sc-1.4.3/sl-1.2.3/datatables.min.css"/>



<div class="container">
  <form action="{{ route('add') }}" method="post">
    <table class="table table-striped data-tables">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>Items</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item[]">
          </td>
          <td>
            Item1
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item[]">
          </td>
          <td>
            Item2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>






<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-3.2.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.4.2/b-colvis-1.4.2/b-flash-1.4.2/b-html5-1.4.2/b-print-1.4.2/cr-1.4.1/fc-3.2.3/fh-3.1.3/kt-2.3.2/r-2.2.0/rg-1.0.2/rr-1.2.3/sc-1.4.3/sl-1.2.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean to say `items` which are selected in the current page are added but not those which are selected in other pages

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
//var dataTableis the object created for your datatable
dataTable.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){

});
```

Comment: hi @Hash, this code is will get all the input type checkbox inside your datatable and then i used the each function to get each result of your checkbox

Comment: What action are you referring inside the `each()` ?

Comment: in my case, what i did is putting the value of each selected value in a form so that i can send my data and get the all selected checkbox. i was unable to submit the entire array as in so i used this method instead